# Is it any way to calling SvelteKit form actions from within children components?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

For example I have a route tree like this

```
foobar_route
|
|-+page.server.js
|-+page.svelte
|-child_component.svelte
|
```

In +page.server.js I have

```js
export const actions = {

    create_content: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
        ...
    }
};
```

In child_component.svelte I have a form like the same one on svelte example page

```
<form method="POST" action="?/create_content">
   <input/>
   <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

And the child_component is called inside +page.svelte

```
<script>
...
</script>
...
<Child_component/>
...
```

But seems like it was not the right way to implemented it since the action was not called from the form within child component.

Is there any other way to use it than use store?

Comment: Deleting and recreating the component seems to fix this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine for me. SvelteKit does nothing special there that would prevent this from working.

Check the console in the browser and the Vite dev server for errors and make sure the form actually works inlined in the page. Maybe you broke something while extracting it or there was an issue from the beginning.

Comment: The returned values from the form are not accessible to me, neither in the child nor the parent component. Could you find a way?

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena: As I stated in the answer, this should just work. Tested it *again* just now, and it also worked. `form` data is only accessible in the `+page.svelte`, for child components it has to be passed or accessed via the [`page` store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-page) (i.e. `$page.form`).

Comment: It just works. I was missing `export` in `export let form: ActionData`. Now I am facing a problem when having multiple forms in the same page, and one of them is handled by the `+page.server.ts` of another page. The form does not return to parent.

Comment: @aldo.roman.nurena: Please ask a separate question, giving all the necessary details/code.